# Install packages as non root user

Tags: apt, server, package-management

Im having problem with privileges on my server machine,

So Im trying to install new package: `net-tools` as my default user on machine named: **appuser**

I do this:

```
appuser: sudo apt install net-tools
```

I get this error:

```
appuser is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

That is ok, im able to install it if I switch to superuser and then do the  install

But Im not being able to run net-rools package as **appuser** only as **superuser**

On the other hand I have node js also installed on system, and Im able to run it as **appuser**, But this or any new package I install I cannot run them from command line as **appuser**.

How can I change or install net-tools, or nginx package to be able for appuser to use it from command line

Comment: *"Im not being able to run net-rools package as appuser "* what happens, exactly, when you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add `appuser` into the sudoers group.
First, open terminal with a user that has sudo permissions. Then, you can run `sudo adduser appuser sudo` to add appuser to the sudoers group. Now you can use `appuser` to run sudo commands.

Comment: Cool thank you will try :)

Comment: But How If I want to run it as appuser but I do not want to add appuser to sudoers

Comment: You can not because you **need** to be a sudoer to be able to run sudo commands. Your command is `**sudo** apt install net-tools` so you need the user you are running this with to be a sudoer.

Comment: Did my answer work? If so, I recommend you accept my answer.

Comment: I have accepted it

Answer (score 0):

Add the user to the sudoers file with full priviledges or some priviledge

Type the following command.

```
   sudo su

   visudo
```

In last line add the following line. Here i full access given to the user

```
   username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Save the file and exit

Now try to install Packages you want.

We also can give Limited priviledge to the user